# How to create a shortcode with html and php code

Tags: shortcode

This how i try it but doesn't work

```
function blogPost(){
    return ?>
    <section class="blog container spacer">
      <article class="blog__list">
       <div class="glide-blog">
          <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
            <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">&lt;</button>
            <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">&gt;</button>
         </div>
       <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
            <ul class="glide__slides">
    
           <?php 
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>
              
            <?php 
            // Start our WP Query
            while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 
            ?>
              
             <li class="glide__slide"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="new-article__main-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
              
            
              
            <?php 
            // Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            </ul>
      </article>
    </section>
    <?php
}
add_action('blog-shortcode','blogPost');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHPs output buffering, using [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to turn on the buffering and [ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to get and delete the current output buffering.

So going by your code it would look like this

```
function blogPost(){
    ob_start();
?>
    <section class="blog container spacer">
        <article class="blog__list">
            <div class="glide-blog">
                <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
                    <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">&lt;</button>
                    <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">&gt;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                    <ul class="glide__slides">
                        <?php 
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' );

                        // Start our WP Query
                        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                        ?>
                        <li class="glide__slide"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="new-article__main-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <?php 
                        // Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('blog_shortcode','blogPost');
```

Notice that instead `add_action` we now have `add_shortcode`, `add_shortcode` is the function you use to create custom shortcodes.

I also fixed a few issues with the code.

- `$the_query -> have_posts()` should not contain spaces between the "arrow", it should be like this `$the_query->have_posts()`.
- Added a few missing closing `</div>` tags.
- Corrected indentation based on the missing `</div>` tags

Comment: Thanks,it's solved my problem